# ASP issue giving me, ERROR: Procedure or function uspPatientUpdate has too many arguments specified

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

What is happening: I'm trying to update a patient table in a gridview table using a stored procedure.

Error:

> 'DropDownList2' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Here is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.uspPatientUpdate
    @ID int,
    @OHIP char(10),
    @FirstName nvarchar(20),
    @LastName nvarchar(40),
    @DOB date,
    @VisitsPerYear int,
    @DoctorID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    UPDATE Patient
    SET OHIP = @OHIP,
      FirstName = @FirstName, 
      LastName = @LastName,
      DOB = @DOB,
      VisitsPerYear = @VisitsPerYear,
      DoctorID = @DoctorID
    WHERE ID = @ID 
END
```

Here is my asp:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MedicalOffice.aspx.cs" Inherits="MedicalOffice" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Maintain Patients</h1>
        <p>Select Patient By Doctor:<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sdDoctorList" DataTextField="Doctor" DataValueField="ID">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="sdPatient" GridLines="Horizontal">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OHIP" SortExpression="OHIP">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OHIP") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OHIP") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visits Per Year" SortExpression="VisitsPerYear">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitsPerYear") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitsPerYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doctor" SortExpression="Doctor">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            #<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdDoctorList" DataTextField="Doctor" DataValueField="ID">#
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Doctor") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" HeaderText="Insert Patient" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OHIP" SortExpression="OHIP">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OHIP") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OHIP") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OHIP") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VisitsPerYear" SortExpression="VisitsPerYear">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitsPerYear") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitsPerYear") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitsPerYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doctor" SortExpression="Doctor">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Doctor") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdDoctorList" DataTextField="Doctor" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Doctor") %>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Doctor") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
                </Fields>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            </asp:DetailsView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdDoctorList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicalOfficeConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="uspDoctorList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </p>

    </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdPatient" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MedicalOfficeConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="usp_PatientDelete" InsertCommand="uspPatientInsert" SelectCommand="uspPatientSelectByIDOrSelectAll" UpdateCommand="uspPatientUpdate" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="OHIP" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VisitsPerYear" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DoctorID" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="doctorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="OHIP" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VisitsPerYear" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DoctorID" Type="Int32" />
<asp:Parameter Name="Timestamp" Type="Object"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="Please fix the following:" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`uspPatientUpdate` is missing the `TimeStamp` parameter:

```
<UpdateParameters>
  ...
  <asp:Parameter Name="Timestamp" Type="Object"></asp:Parameter>
</UpdateParameters>
```

Or, perhaps it isn't missing it and you simply shouldn't specify it in the markup.

Comment: But now, if I insert the timestamp in my procedure, I get the following error:
Operand type clash: sql_variant is incompatible with timestamp

Comment: I'm having an issue now where it's not updating the parameters once I try to update them. It doesn't give me any error message. :3